# Cannot post activity. Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, botframework, bot-emulator

For some reason, I am unable to start even the simplest bot in Bot Framework Emulator.

Steps to reproduce:

1. In VS2019, create new Echo Bot (Bot Framework v4 - .NET Core 3.1) project (using Bot Framework v4 SDK Templates for Visual Studio)
2. Run project without making any changes whatsoever (empty strings for `MicrosoftAppIdand` and `MicrosoftAppPasswordin` in `appsettings.json`)
3. Start Bot Framework Emulator

[image]

[image]

[image]

http://localhost:3978/ opens up in the browser without issue but in the Emulator I  get the below errors:

`Cannot post activity. Unauthorized.`

`POST 401 directline/conversations/<conversationId>/activities`

What could be causing these errors with such a minimal project? My understanding is this should just work straight out of the box when running on localhost and no security credentials have been provided.

I am using a work computer and I'm wondering if there is something 'behind the scenes' blocking a connection somewhere/somehow? I have no idea where to look, though. It works fine on another computer and was working fine on this machine when I last tried a couple of months ago so I'm really confused.

Any clues or suggestions on how to debug this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `https` instead of http.